# vb.net Function for Percentage of Html

Tags: html, .net, vb.net

I have some articles saved in database.On certain pages I wanted to show certain percentage of the article based on some settings.
e.g. 80% of the article

Problem is that as html is not plain text if I take certain percentage of the string length then formatting get disturbed 
Can any help me in some function where I provide string and new length (which will be less then the old string length)
And it will return me truncated html without disturbing the formating
I have tried with

```
Private Function HtmlSubstring(html As String, maxlength As Integer) As String
        'initialize regular expressions
        Dim htmltag As String = "</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:"".*?""|'.*?'|[^'"">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>"
        Dim emptytags As String = "<(\w+)((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:"".*?""|'.*?'|[^'"">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?></\1>"

        'match all html start and end tags, otherwise get each character one by one..
        Dim expression As Regex = New Regex(String.Format("({0})|(.?)", htmltag))
        Dim matches As MatchCollection = expression.Matches(html)

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim content As New StringBuilder()
        For Each match As Match In matches
            If match.Value.Length = 1 AndAlso i < maxlength Then
                content.Append(match.Value)
                i += 1
                'the match contains a tag
            ElseIf match.Value.Length > 1 Then
                content.Append(match.Value)
            End If
        Next

        Return Regex.Replace(content.ToString(), emptytags, String.Empty)
    End Function
```

But didn't work always

Comment: I'm not sure what's being asked here, could you clarify where you're having an issue?

Comment: I am using dotnetnuke blog module.What i am rendering blog entries from database table where html of entries are saved in db. Theere i have made a desktop module in which one control i have to show only certain percentage of the article. 
It is an interesting requirement
Now if i take substring of the html then i am sure to ,loose the indentation and possible closing of the html tags
So i needed a funtion where i input string (which is html for) and new length and it will rerurn truncated html provided that there is not formating lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally following has work quite well for me

```
 Private Function HtmlSubstring(ByRef html As String, maxlength As Integer) As String
    'initialize regular expressions
    Const htmltag As String = "</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:"".*?""|'.*?'|[^'"">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>"
    'match all html start and end tags, otherwise get each character one by one..
    Dim expression As Regex = New Regex(String.Format("({0})|(.?)", htmltag))
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = expression.Matches(html)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim isEndingSet As Boolean = False
    Dim content As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    For Each match As Match In matches
        If match.Value.Length = 1 AndAlso i < maxlength Then
            content.Append(match.Value)
            'the match contains a tag
            i += 1
        ElseIf match.Value.Length > 1 Then
            If (isEndingSet AndAlso (match.Value.ToLower() = "<br />" OrElse match.Value.ToLower() = "<br>")) Then
                Continue For
            End If
            content.Append(match.Value)
        End If
        If (i = maxlength AndAlso Not isEndingSet) Then
            content.Append("....")
            isEndingSet = True
        End If
    Next

    Return content.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Heinzi about describing how to answer my own question.Previously i was thinking a user can't answer it's own post

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that there is no built-in .NET method to do what you ask. However, consider the following method:

Your HTML page is probably structured, i.e., it has paragraphs, headings, etc.:

```
<h1>...</h1>
<p>...</p>
<h2>...</h2>
<p>...<more tags>...</more tags></p>
<h2>...</h2>
<p>...</p>
...
```

What you could do is:

1. Use a HTML parser (the [HTML agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is often mentioned in this context) and parse your HTML into a data structure.
2. Take the first 80% *of the top-level tags*. For example, if the root node of your HTML content has ten children, take the first eight:

   ```
   <h1>...</h1>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <h2>...</h2>
   <p>
      ...
      <more tags>
         ...
      </more tags>
      ...
   </p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...<more tags>...</more tags>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   ---------------
   <h2>...</h2>
   <p>...</p>
   ```

If your article is *approximately* evenly spaced (i.e., your long and short paragraphs average out over the course of the article), this will give you *approximately* 80% of the text without breaking any HTML formatting. As an additional benefit, you won't be splitting the text mid-line or mid-paragraph.

Comment: I have edited referred something from http://www.koodr.com/snippet/438c2e9c/use-regular-expression-to-get-a-substring-of-text-which-contains-html-content

But it isn't working correctly always

Comment: @KamranShahid: That's because parsing HTML with regular expressions [is a very difficult thing](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). I really recommend using a parser instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Heinrich Moser. 
Will give a bit of effort otherwise will

Comment: How can i accept a post as answer here.Also the solution posted by me i am sure will help others as well.
IT is not correct to mark this post as no research work category

Comment: @KamranShahid: You don't have to add your answer to the question, you can add your answer as an *answer* by clicking the "Answer Your Question" button at the bottom. You can then also accept it as the correct answer.